the column names are not as per the expectation
I am using the below code to generate the mean and std of numeric column of class dataframe. I am expecting the names of the new columns to be Age_mean, Age_std instead of Age.Age_mean, Age.Age_std.
not sure why the Age. is additionally added to the column names
Here is the data and code i used
class <- structure(list(Name = c("Alfred", "Alice", "Barbara", "Carol", 
"Henry", "James", "Jane", "Janet", "Jeffrey", "John", "Joyce", 
"Judy", "Louise", "Mary", "Philip", "Robert", "Ronald", "Thomas", 
"William"), Sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), Age = c(14, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 12, 12, 15, 13, 12, 11, 14, 12, 15, 16, 12, 15, 
11, 15), Height = c(69, 56.5, 65.3, 62.8, 63.5, 57.3, 59.8, 62.5, 
62.5, 59, 51.3, 64.3, 56.3, 66.5, 72, 64.8, 67, 57.5, 66.5), 
    Weight = c(112.5, 84, 98, 102.5, 102.5, 83, 84.5, 112.5, 
    84, 99.5, 50.5, 90, 77, 112, 150, 128, 133, 85, 112)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -19L))


out1 <- list()

calc_mean <- function(data, vars, out) {
 
  vars <- syms(vars)
  print(vars)
  for (v in vars){
    print(v)
  out1[[v]] <- data %>% summarise('{{v}}_mean' := mean(!! v), '{{v}}_std' := sd(!! v))
  out2 <-  data.frame(out1)
  assign(out, out2, envir =.GlobalEnv)
  }

  return(out2)
}

calc_mean(data=class, vars=c('Age','Height'), out='want')


output
  Age.Age_mean Age.Age_std Height.Height_mean Height.Height_std
1     13.31579    1.492672           62.33684          5.127075


They're probably added because of vars values ("Age" and "Height"). One way that always works is to rename the output afterwards, but here's another approach using all tidy verbs without for looping using all_of.
library(dplyr)

calc_mean_std <- function(df, vars){
  df %>% summarize(across(all_of(vars), \(x) mean(x), .names="{.col}_mean"), 
                   across(all_of(vars), \(x) sd(x), .names="{.col}_std"))
}

output
take <- c("Age", "Height")

calc_mean_std(data, take)
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  Age_mean Height_mean Age_std Height_std
     <dbl>       <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>
1     13.3        62.3    1.49       5.13

Note, I wouldn't name the data class since it potentially clashes with class
Data
data <- structure(list(Name = c("Alfred", "Alice", "Barbara", "Carol", 
"Henry", "James", "Jane", "Janet", "Jeffrey", "John", "Joyce", 
"Judy", "Louise", "Mary", "Philip", "Robert", "Ronald", "Thomas", 
"William"), Sex = c("M", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "F", "F", "M", 
"M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M"), Age = c(14, 
13, 13, 14, 14, 12, 12, 15, 13, 12, 11, 14, 12, 15, 16, 12, 15, 
11, 15), Height = c(69, 56.5, 65.3, 62.8, 63.5, 57.3, 59.8, 62.5, 
62.5, 59, 51.3, 64.3, 56.3, 66.5, 72, 64.8, 67, 57.5, 66.5), 
    Weight = c(112.5, 84, 98, 102.5, 102.5, 83, 84.5, 112.5, 
    84, 99.5, 50.5, 90, 77, 112, 150, 128, 133, 85, 112)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -19L))

Your naming happens here '{{v}}_mean' := mean(!! v) when you assign the name and here
data.frame(out1) when the list of tibbles is cast into a dataframe.
This is an intermediate output after data.frame(out1)
$Age
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  Age_mean Age_std
     <dbl>   <dbl>
1     13.3    1.49

$Height
# A tibble: 1 × 2
  Height_mean Height_std
        <dbl>      <dbl>
1        62.3       5.13

This gets cast into e.g. Age.Age_mean
You can either use summarise('mean' := mean(!! v), 'std' := sd(!! v)) to avoid the repeated names or add names(out1) <- NULL after summarize to get the desired result with your code.

Thank you, this is helpful. However, I want to understand the how i can modify my code to get the expected results, i tried using across and it works if i am using i stats, but if i use multiple stats then i dont get expected output

I added a short explanation why this repetitive naming happens.
